# How to hide custom tab when no content is present in woocommerce single products page

Tags: woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have used ACF plugin (Advance custom field plugin ) for custom tab and their field.
http://mp.indiskart.no/butikk/shampo-sape-og-krem/bodylotion-200-ml/
Kindly help me out, if any single product page custom tab content or field is empty then how to hide this custom tab,

Comment: please can show us the code you use to display this custom tab?

Comment: we dont have used any code for this tab. We have used Advance custom field plugin for this custom tab ( i.e. Product details and Product description) and custom field.
Now we want to use using custom code or something else to resolve this hide custom menu if it is empty.

Comment: no code in the template to display the tab?